# Como puedo ir a una linea y hacer esa parte del codigo infinita

Tags: python

Este es el codigo , su objetivo es hablar a traves de webhooks de discord , pero luego de que envias el primer mensaje se cierra , mi objetivo es que puedas enviar ilimitados mensajes

```
link = input("URL Del webhook: ")
print()
nombre = input("Nombre Del webhook: ")
print()
foto = input("Foto de perfil del webhook: ")
print()
texto = input(">")

url = link
codigojson = {
  "content": texto,
  "username": nombre,
  "avatar_url": foto
}

x = requests.post(url, json = codigojson)
```

He intentado con loop (No lo entendi) , y con el modulo goto (no funciono) , ayuda parfavar uwu

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: PAra la proxima, cuando dices que intentaste algo, muestralo tambien...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a meter todo en una función y llamar a esa función con While true, así:

```
import time

def funcion():
    link = input("URL Del webhook: ")
    print()
    nombre = input("Nombre Del webhook: ")
    print()
    foto = input("Foto de perfil del webhook: ")
    print()
    texto = input(">")
    url = link
    codigojson = {
      "content": texto,
      "username": nombre,
      "avatar_url": foto
    }

    x = requests.post(url, json = codigojson)

    
While True:
   funcion()
   time.sleep(60)
```

Cada 60 segundos, el código volverá a ser ejecutado. Espero te sirva :)

Comment: Bueno, acabo de leerlo bien, mete dentro de la función sólo la línea de código que quieres que se ejecute todo el tiempo.

Comment: Por alguna razon no corre amigo , que podria ser? Disculpe la molestia!

Comment: No te aparece algún tipo de error por pantalla que nos pueda dar una pista?

Comment: Solucionado!, era tan simple como poner lo que queria que se repitiera en el while true , nada de funciones